# jquery: How to make query just for one <div> element in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following code is to add a css class to  element, but this code will add this class to all  elements present in a form.

```
$("#user_text").change(function(){

  if($("#user_text").val().length <= 6){
    $("div").addClass("has-error");
  }else{
    $("div").addClass();
  }
});
```

I have 5 more  elements in my form but i want this code to work just for a particular  element. this is the HTML code for it:

```
<div class="form-group">

      <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="user_text">Text</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">  
      <input class="form-control" id="user_text" name="user[text]" placeholder="Enter password" type="text" />
</div>
</div>
<script>
$("#user_password").change(function(){

  if($("#user_password").val().length <= 6){
    $("div").addClass("has-error");
  }else{
    $("div").addClass();
  }
});
</script>
```

Is there any way I can just use my code for the particular  element? little help...

Comment: Which div? Can you post HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Use `id` for that particular `div` Example  : `<div id="example"></div>`

```
$("#user_text").change(function(){

   if($("#user_text").val().length <= 6){
 $("#example").addClass("has-error"); // It will add class to that example id div
   }else{
      $("#example").removeClass("has-error");
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#user_text").change(function(){ 
  if($(this).val().length <= 6){
    $("div#dvId").addClass("has-error");
  }else{
    $("div#dvId").removeClass("has-error");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `$("div")` selector more specific, e.g. `$(".a-parent-element div")` or `$("div.my-css-class")`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you can go with special filters maybe:

```
$("#user_text").change(function(){

  if($("#user_text").val().length <= 6){
    $("div:first").addClass("has-error");
  }else{
    $("div:first").addClass();
  }
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/jquery-selector-extensions/